# chrome.storage.local.set()... Content-script can't access stored value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio][name=csvOrEnter_radio]').change(function () {
        var val = GetSlectedRadioValue('csvOrEnter_radio', 'csvOrEnter_form');
        //console.log(val);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'csvOrEnter': val }, function () { });
    });

    $('input[type=radio][name=filteringStrategy_radio]').change(function () {
        var val = GetSlectedRadioValue('filteringStrategy_radio', 'filteringStrategy_form');
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'filteringStrategy': val }, function () { });
    });
});

function GetSlectedRadioValue(radioName, formID) {
    return $('input[name=' + radioName + ']:checked', '#' + formID).val();
```

The code above is separated script (meeting Chrome CSP), declared in my popup.html as `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`. Console logging shows that it works.

So the values from radiobautton, located on the popup.html are set to chrome storage. But when I call them from my content-script:

```
var csvOrEnter = "";
chrome.storage.local.get('csvOrEnter_radio', function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    csvOrEnter = result.csvOrEnter_radio;
    console.log(csvOrEnter);
});
```

...it returns 'undefined'. The 'result' is plain empty object. What am I missing here?

Comment: Uhm, different keys: `csvOrEnter` when saving, `csvOrEnter_radio` when reading.

Comment: @wOxxOm THX A LOT. Seems that I am kind of stuipid ;)))))

Comment: See [Inspect chrome.storage.sync while debugging Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/32471596)